# Calculate Totals for a column of Text Values

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a column of data that contains various string values, (Grade 01, Grade 02, Grade 03, etc...). What I would like to calculate total number of each value.

Example:

- Total Grade 01 =
- Total Grade 02 =
- Total Grade 03 =

etc..

How do I go about calculating the sum for each individual column value?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Count distinct on that field.

Comment: Depending on the data and report design you may be forced to create a manual running total.

Comment: Count distinct will certainly not work. That will count the number of grades represented, not the number of records having a given grade.

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  2 questions, Pete.  First, does this report have any groupings? i.e., is it grouped by grade? Second, where do you want the result to appear?

Answer (score 0):

If that's the entirety of the report:

1. Group by the grade field.
2. Insert a summary in the group header or footer. Summarize on the grade field (in fact the field doesn't matter), and specify **Count** as the summary formula.
3. Suppress the detail section.

If this is just a part of the report, insert a subreport, with no linked fields, and follow those steps in the subreport instead.

Comment: thanks for all the advice. I actually discovered cross-tabs, which answered this question plus a whole lot more.

Comment: If you're all set, click the Close link under the question. It's right below the tags.